# Accuracy of clock_gettime() in a context switch scenario

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, context-switch

I'm trying to 'roughly' calculate the time of a thread context switch in a Linux system. I've written a program that uses pipes and multi-threading to achieve this. When running the program the calculated time is clearly wrong(see output below). I am unsure if this is due to me using the wrong clock_id for this procedure or perhaps my implementation

I have implemented sched_setaffinity() so as to only have the program run on core 0. I've tried to leave as much fluff out of code so to only measure the time of a context switch, so the tread process only writes a single character to the pipe and the parent does a 0 byte read.

I have a parent tread that creates one child thread with a one-way pipe between them to pass data, the child thread runs a simple function to write to a pipe.

```
    void* thread_1_function()
    {
         write(fd2[1],"",sizeof("");
    }
```

while the parent thread creates the child thread, starts the time counter and then calls a read on the pipe that the child thread writes to.

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
//time struct declaration
struct timespec start,end;

//sets program to only use core 0
cpu_set_t cpu_set;
CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
CPU_SET(0,&cpu_set);


if((sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu_set) < 1))
{

int nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
int k;

printf("Processor used: ");
for(k = 0; k < nproc; ++k)
{
    printf("%d ", CPU_ISSET(k, &cpu_set));
}

printf("\n");


if(pipe(fd1) == -1)
{
    printf("fd1 pipe error");
    return 1;
}
//fail on file descriptor 2 fail
if(pipe(fd2) == -1)
{
    printf("fd2 pipe error");
    return 1;
}


pthread_t thread_1;


pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, &thread_1_function, NULL);


pthread_join(thread_1,NULL);


int i;
uint64_t sum = 0;

for(i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
{

    //initalize clock start
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    //wait for child thread to write to pipe
    read(fd2[0],input,0);
    //record clock end
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);   

    write(fd1[1],"",sizeof(""));



    uint64_t diff;
    diff = billion * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    diff = diff;
    sum += diff;
}
```

The results i get while running this are typically in this manner:

```
     3000
     3000
     4000
     2000
     12000
     3000
     5000
```

and so forth, when I inspect the time returned to the start and end timespec structs i see that tv_nsec seems to be a 'rounded' number as well:

```
     start.tv_nsec: 714885000, end.tv_nsec: 714888000
```

Would this be caused by a clock_monotonic not being precise enough for what im attempting to measure, or some other problem that i'm overlooking?

Comment: Can you show your code (see [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). It is unusual to use a pipe between threads. Are you considering threads or forked processes?

Comment: I'm having trouble following parts of your wording.  For example, you seem to be using the terms "thread" and "process" interchangeably, but these are different things.  And I'm having great difficulty matching "tv_nsec is the same albeit on a larger scale" to the data you actually present.

Comment: Overall, I'm uncertain of the basis for your claim that "the calculated time is clearly wrong", but also uncertain of why you think your approach (which you do not seem to have fully disclosed) serves to measure the context-switch time.  These are related, for if you're actually measuring something else instead then whatever expectation you may have about the results is probably invalid.

Comment: edited to add more code, and adjusted for clarity between process and thread.

Comment: My claim comes from using clock_gettime in previous learning adventures and it never being returned with what i consider an unprecise number, i.e the amount of trailing zeros, that make me feel as if its a rounded number( which from reading the docs, I am aware its not)

Comment: @AlainMerigot, I'm open to either forked process or threads, It's just a learning example for me to better understand whats happening

Comment: Are you compiling your program in 64 bit mode (e.g. `x86_64`)? If not, this will affect the `rvalue` of the `diff` calculation. What is the exact type/definition of `billion`? Is it [hopefully] also `uint64_t`?

Comment: Just to be sure, you may want to call `clock_getres` to verify that `clock_gettime` uses nanosecond precision. (e.g.) linux will use it as will most other POSIX OSes (e.g. *BSD, MacOSX), but since you're experiencing issues ... `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` [if supported, which it is in many places] is similar to `CLOCK_REALTIME` except that it _never_ goes backwards in time. You could try it with both options to see.

Answer (score 1):

> i see that tv_nsec seems to be a 'rounded' number as well:
>
> ```
>  2626, 714885000, 2626, 714888000
> ```
>
> Would this be caused by a clock_monotonic not being precise enough for
>   what im attempting to measure, or some other problem that i'm
>   overlooking?

Yes, that's a possibility.  Every clock supported by the system has a fixed resolution. `struct timespec` is capable of supporting clocks with nanosecond resolution, but that does not mean that you can expect every clock to actually *have* such resolution.  It looks like your `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` might have a resolution of 1 microsecond (1000 nanoseconds), but you can check that via the `clock_getres()` function.

If it is available to you, then you might try `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`.  It is possible that that would have higher resolution than `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for you, but do note that single-microsecond resolution is pretty precise -- that's on the order of one tick per 3000 CPU cycles on a modern machine.

---

Even so, I see several possible problems with your approach:

- Although you set your process to have affinity for a single CPU, that does not prevent the system from scheduling other processes on that CPU, too.  Thus, unless you've taken additional measures, you can't be certain -- it's not even likely -- that every context switch away from one of your program's threads is *to* the other thread.
- You start your second thread and then immediately join it.  There is no more context switching between your threads after that, because your second thread no longer exists after being successfully joined.
- `read()` with a count of 0 may or may not check for errors, and it certainly does not transfer any data.  It is totally unclear to me why you identify the time for that call with the time for a context switch.
- If a context switch does occur in the space you're timing, then at least two need to occur there -- away from your program and back to it.  Also, you're measuring the time consumed by whatever else runs in the other context as well, not just the switch time.  The 1000-nanosecond steps may thus reflect time slices, rather than switching time.
- Your main thread is writing null characters to the write end of a pipe, but there does not appear to be anything reading them.  If indeed there isn't then this will eventually fill up the pipe's buffer and block.  The purpose is lost on me.